# MAUI ad hoc ipa file from visual studio error unable to install app integrity could not be verified

Tags: ios, maui

1. I Created the certificate using Windows Visual Studio and it automatically installed in my mac keychain since I use Pair to Mac.
   Certificate status is valid for both windows and mac keychain.
2. I create Identifiers use the bundle id registered in my project properties: bundle signing
3. My device (Iphone) is already registered since I try to use a local device for testing. Double checked the UDID.
4. I create Profile Provisioning and used the valid certificate and choose all devices.
5. Project Property> Ios >
   Scheme: Manual Provisioning
   Signing Identity: Distribution(Automatic)
   Profile: Automatic
   Publish using windows visual studio
6. Click Distibute and choose Ad Hoc
7. Save Ipa File and download a copy to my mac
8. Connect my phone to mac and try to drag and drop the ipa file
9. Open the app from my phone then the error occurs. (unable to install app integrity could not be verified)

WHAT TO DO? :{

Comment: What codesign error did it say? Can you build the app successfully on a physical device using pair to mac?

Comment: Upon trying to use the certificate and profile ad hoc type I created in my developer account I successfully publish it and created an ipa file. But still I have error unable to install app integrity could not be verified.

Is there anything I should do to my phone settings? as I am seing a lot when they are trying to install apps that wasnt in app store.

Comment: Here is a similar issue,[internal use app can't be installed because its integrity could not be verified](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698503).